# Compile a package in node_modules for use in browser

Tags: meteor

I just noticed that, because meteor doesn't compile packages in `node_modules`, our website doesn't load on iOS 10. iOS 10 is currently used on more than 16% of iOS devices, according to this source: https://data.apteligent.com/ios/ (this is quite high)

I did some research and found out that you can choose which node_modules packages to compile, but it's only coming in the next meteor release: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9771
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

Any way to have this functionality sooner?

Should I just "git clone" the package and compile it manually (how?) and then include the compile version and remove the npm-installed package?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add the npm package as a git submodule (or subtree) inside your `imports` folder and then import it from there, as though it was your own code. This will trigger Meteor's build tool.

By keeping it as a git submodule you can always update it by checking out a new version inside that folder, and keep it's code separate from your own repo.

Note that having submodules increases the complexity of using git and working with your project in general.

Before you do that though, I would try symlinking the package from node_modules into your imports folder somewhere and importing from `/imports/`. I know they've said this will only work in future versions but I wouldn't be surprised if it can work now