# Which meteor file should npm import statements go?

Tags: meteor, npm

We are working on an old meteor project that is being upgraded to 1.8 and we need to be able to change some of the old meteor packages to the npm versionvs (moment for example).

The problem we have struck is that we can't seem to work out which file in the whole tree we need to put the import statements because so far, wherever we put it, we get the following error in the web console.

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

We have tried pretty much all of the files in client including startup.js but can't crack it.

Where should these import declarations go?

Answer (score 1):

This message means that your client browser bundle does not get properly transpiled. This can be for 2 reasons:

- your Meteor project does not transpile code to ES5 syntax, e.g. if it lacks `ecmascript` package, or babel, babel runtime, etc.
- you import a file from `node_modules` that still has this `import` keyword: by default, Meteor assumes that npm modules are already usable as-is and are not recompiled (for performance). Most of the time this is because the default imported file of the npm module is in esm form (the file specified in `"main"` field of `package.json`), but usually a transpiled or bundled form is also shipped. In that case, simply import explicitly that dist / transpiled file instead of the default package file.

In some cases, some modules do not ship such transpiled version. In that case, you will have to transpile it yourself first. See also [Compile a package in node_modules for use in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742171/compile-a-package-in-node-modules-for-use-in-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ghybs, but I'm not getting anywhere. I have meteor npm install --save @babel@latest and moment. I've tried sudo npm install --global moment. Tried to run without the import and got variable not defined.. still no joy.

Comment: `"main"` field of `package.json` file of [`momentjs`](https://github.com/moment/moment/) library points to a file without any `import` statement, so it is not your offender. You would need to look for the library that you import that still has this keyword. In development mode (`meteor run`), the browser syntax error should point you to a bundled non-minified file that gives you a hint on the library in which the keyword is used.